# A pendulum with the moving pivot

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, computational-physics

I want to simulate a pendulum whose pivot moves along $x$-direction with some given trajectory $x_p(t)$. The connecting rode is rigid.

[image]

I derived the following system of equations:

$$y^2 + (x_p-x)^2 = L^2$$

$$-Mg + N\sin\theta = Mx''$$

$$N\cos\theta = My'',$$

where $M$ is the blob mass, $\theta$ is the angle between the rode and the $y$-axis, $x_p$ pivot position, $x$ and $y$ positions of the blob.

**Question:** how can I solve this system numerically?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Lagrangian formalism? Or do you want/need this to be done in the Newtonian formalism?

Comment: You can implement these equations using any preferred language. Then for your derivatives, there many ways you can do, like Finite differences. Or if you use Mathematica, then you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: You have three variables which are all directly related to each other, so you'd be making your numerical solver do a lot of unnecessary work. Try deriving a single equation of motion for $\theta$ that only involves $x_p(t)$ and $L$. Once you have that, you can easily compute $x(t)$ and $y(t)$.

Comment: With \begin{aligned}x=L\sin \left( \theta \right) \\
y=L\cos \left( \theta \right) \end{aligned} you obtain one deferential equation for $\ddot\theta$

Comment: This would be an interesting problem in a vacuum, but in air drag from motion along the x axis will damp the pendulum motion down to something looking like your picture, without swinging.  Drag force vectors must be included for moving objects.  This problem is a bit like a helicopter carrying a bucket of water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this type of problem is using the Lagrangian approach. The Lagrangian is the kinetic energy minus the potential energy: $$ \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}m \left( \dot x^2 +\dot y^2 \right)- m g y $$ Then we can make the substitutions $x \rightarrow L \sin(\theta) + x_p$ and $y \rightarrow -L \cos(\theta)$. Making those substitutions and simplifying gives $$ \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}m \left( \dot x_p^2 + L^2 \dot \theta^2 + 2 L \cos(\theta) \left( g+ \dot x_p \dot \theta \right) \right) $$ Since $x_p$ is a known input, this is a Lagrangian in only one coordinate, $\theta$. So we can immediately write the Euler Lagrange equation for $\theta$ and simplify to obtain $$\ddot \theta = -\frac{1}{R} \left( g \sin(\theta) + \ddot x_p \cos(\theta) \right)$$ With just this single equation you should be able to plug it into pretty much any numerical differential equation solver to get an answer. Note, the equation of motion for $\theta$ depends on $\ddot x_p$, not on $x_p$ or $\dot x_p$. This makes sense because you can always choose a reference frame where $x_p(0)=\dot x_p(0)=0$